# set the cookies for subdomain

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I tried to set the cookies for a subdomain with https. I am setting the cookies at node side. Its working correctly with Http and without domain but when I try it with domain and https it's not working.

This is the code which I tried for https :-

```
  let cookiesotp = new Cookies(req, res, { keys: keysotp }) // for one month coooke set 
  cookiesotp.set('LastVisit',new Date().toISOString(),{ domain: '.makeitdouble.com',  path: '/', secure: true,HttpOnly:true, signed: true,maxAge:2628000000});
```

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: @GrafiCode No, I am not getting any error

Comment: @GrafiCode but when I print cookiesotp variable in this secure and domain is showing undefined

Comment: I'm really puzzled, just one more question: does the `domain` property work on standard http? I ask because it might have nothing to do with ssl.

Comment: @GrafiCode no at Http I am not setting domain

Comment: that's why I am asking, can you please try and set the `domain` property on non-https?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203765/discussion-between-mangita-and-graficode).

Comment: @GrafiCode  I tried but its not working with subdomain